# Confiigure JVM setting in Jetty standalone server

Tags: jetty

I'm trying to install a standalone jetty 7.6.3 server in CENTOS. I was able successfully deploy and run a sample application with default settings.
Now i want to increase the JVM memory, that is set the Xmx and Xms parameters. After reading through the documentation i have set them in start.ini file. But this is not getting reflected when i start the server. I have tried using --exec parameter in start.ini, but this spawns a separate VM.
I'm using java -jar start.jar to start the server

How do i configure the JVM memory GC setting in a jetty standalone server?

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `JAVA_OPTIONS` in the `jetty.sh` file.

Comment: Can you please share exact configs that needs to be added in jetty.sh? Its accepted answer but can have more details :)

Answer (score 0):

Go to $JETTY_HOME/bin/jetty.sh and update JAVA_OPTIONS parameter:

```
JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -server -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC"
```

I used Jetty 9.2.9 and change worked for me.